# Tkinter - Multiple windows opening

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Like the title says I'm having a problem with multiple windows being able to open. New window (same window) every time I click the button. I haven't been able to find an answer to this specific scenario. I've even tried disabling the button after opening window (which led to the problem of re-enabling).

Below is enough code to work with, you can see the problem by clicking the button a few times. I am hoping for a somewhat easy solution as I am fairly new to Tkinter. Also, the smaller window needs to resize (expand) with the main window, so I dont think a Toplevel window would work.

There may be others having this same problem, and thanks in advance!

Note: I'm using Python 2.7 (Tkinter)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from ScrolledText import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox

# Main
root = tk.Tk(className = "tex")
root.geometry("500x300")
root.title("tex")
tex = ScrolledText(root, padx=2, pady=2, undo=True, font=('Arial 11'))

def note_area():
    btn_frame = Frame()
    note = LabelFrame(tex, bd=1, relief='ridge')

    tx = Text(note, width=18, relief='flat', padx=2, pady=2)
    tx.insert('1.0', "Notes..")
    tx.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    note.pack(side='right', fill=Y)
    btn_frame.pack(side='bottom', fill=Y)

# ToolBar Button  (should only open one instance of note_area)
toolbar = Frame(root, bd=2, relief='groove')
b4 = Button(toolbar, text="Notes", width=4, command=note_area)
b4.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=4, pady=2)
toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

tex.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need make up a variable to keep track of if you have a note window open or not.

```
tex.notes_open = False
def note_area():
    if tex.notes_open: 
        return # abort the function, notes already open
    else:
        tex.notes_open = True # set the flag for the next time
        # rest of your code
```

Comment: If I close notes window, I cant open it again. Any trick to that?